# Understanding Pandas read_excel() behaviour when sheet name is specified or not

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I noticed this different behaviour in `read_excel()` when for the same excel file I declare, or not, the `sheet_name`.

I have one excel file, **with only one sheet** with the default Microsoft Excel sheet name `"Sheet1"`

If I read this file through:

```
df.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=0)
```

I get these columns:

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'A Value', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3',
       'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8',
       'Unnamed: 9', 'Unnamed: 10', 'Unnamed: 11'],
      dtype='object')
```

If I read the file declaring the sheet I get the **expected output**:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 
                   header=0,
                   sheet_name='Sheet1'
                   )
```

And this are the columns:

```
Index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3','column4', 'column5',... ,'column70'],
      dtype='object')
```

What is different is also the reading time.

In the first case is quick:

```
time: 27.6 ms (started: 2022-10-04 10:11:03 +00:00)
```

In the second one(the right one) is definitely slower:

```
time: 1min 2s (started: 2022-10-04 10:41:54 +00:00)
```

Why pandas function read excel has this different behaviour?

[Link to the Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: What version of pandas are you using ? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: @abokey I am using `1.3.5`

Comment: The behaviour you describe looks like you have more then one worksheet. Look for hidden sheets. Note, that there's [3 levels of visibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsheetvisibility) in Excel. See for all sheet objects in the VBA IDE (Alt+F11)

Comment: p.s. Note that by default the sheet with index 0 is read by `pandas.read_excel`. Far not always the very first worksheet is named Sheet1, and Sheet1 isn't necessary the very first one.

Comment: @Vitalizzare I didn't know that and you were right, thanks also for Alt+F11 ![Here the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/12wtCck) . There is a way to spot hidden sheet from `Pandas` or open a ticket on git hub to develop this feature (if it can be useful)?

Comment: @AndreaCiufo `pandas` isn't made to work with Excel files. Actually it uses other packages to read and write those files such as `openpyxl` for example. We can use them directly to test an excel book: `import openpyxl as xl; wb = xl.open(my_book); for sh in wb.sheetnames: print(sh, wb[sh].sheet_state)`. But if we are talking about Windows or Apple with Office installed, IMO it's better to learn the book in the Office before opening it in pandas.

Comment: @Vitalizzare you are perfectly right. I use `Google Colab` and I created a small data pipeline to extract monthly data from an excel file, but the accountant changed the sheet structure. This is an issue when you work with very fragmented environment.